# When does the replication scripts get executed on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-administration

Really silly question I believe, but I couldn't easily find an answer to this question in the web...

I assume that the scripts get executed when some data is inserted/deleted/updated in any table, am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: as with any good answer...it depends. There are 3 different kids of replication see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx) for more details. Within Transactional Replication, there can be different timings too depending on how it is configured. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) for more information.

Comment: the following is a very good article; read the whole thing:  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-replication-crib-sheet/